# how to set traffic arrival time on your own scapy

Tags: python, networking, packet, scapy, traffic

This is my script to generate http traffic

```
from scapy.all import *
from random import randint
import time
from threading import *

# Generate packet
pkts = IP(src="10.0.0.1",dst="10.0.0.2")/TCP()/"GET /HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"/Raw(RandString(size=120))
#print pkts
pkts[TCP].flags = "S"
pktList = []
for pktNum in range(0,20):
    pktList.extend(pkts)
    pktList[pktNum][TCP].dport = randint(1,65535) # Pkt has Ran PortNo.
    print pktList[pktNum].summary()
    print len(pktList[pktNum])

# Send the list of packets
start_time=time.time()
send(pktList)
print time.time() - start_time,"seconds"
#print start_time, "secs"
pktList[0].show()
```

Now the issue is I am not been able to send the traffic at a customize Byte/sec Rate. How Would I be able to send according to my own needs ?

Answer (score 3):

Please, refer to the documentation on [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf), specifically page 35. You may specify the rate by varying the `inter` parameter in the `send` command.

For example to achieve the rate of 100 packets per second you may write:

```
send(pktList, inter = 0.01)
```

To have more control you may use [sendpfast](http://tritm.wikispaces.com/Scapy) command from scapy where you can define the bitrate (mbps argument):

```
sendpfast(pkt, pps=N, mbps=N, loop=0, iface=N)
```

Comment: Basically I want the burst rate of the traffic i.e. at what speed(Bytes/sec) the packets are transmitted to the network.I want to control it not the time to wait between two packets.
For example, if packets are transmitted at a rate of 1500 bytes/sec. The next time I generate traffic I want to lower or faster it depending on my needs.

Comment: And what about If I have to use Poisson Traffic Generation Model. How would I do that ?

Comment: Plus this doesn't works well and taking around 1.50s secs to send 50 packets with or without using inter=0.01

Comment: As far as I see, when you generate Poisson traffic you care about arrival time of packets, not actual bitrate. Poisson traffic has exponential distribution of interarrival times so you may send packets one by one and vary delay between them with `time.sleep(x)` where you sample `x` from the exponential distribution

Comment: Works fine for me, what do you see in Wireshark?

Comment: Basically I want to generate poisson traffic over different traffic flows like one kind of traffic sent at different rate, the other must be at different using the Poisson process. How would I do that?

Comment: 2 separate threads with send() functions. You need exponential distribution for time between packets

Comment: how to achieve taht ? Can you please quote an example using poisson ?

Comment: http://web.iitd.ac.in/~dharmar/soft/PoissonProcess.m check this out on how to generate interarrival time (it's in Matlab, very similar to Python).  `T(i+1)-T(i)` - is the time to wait between packets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832834/backgroundworker-in-python - please, check my post on how to run something in parallel in Python